# Rails: How can a user input data into an Active Record Query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I read through the API for Active Record Querying, but it doesn't seem to include a method for the user to actually input search data. I assume I could somehow link_to a method which contains the query code, but how could I use specific search params? Let's say I only want to search by name for matching instances of one model.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out [rails casts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form)

Comment: @ken-anderson I am sure you could have done a simple Google search to get this answer

Comment: @auL5agoi I checked but the only source I found was the API. If you have been able to find helpful links please post them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simple way to do it is

`Model.find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])`

in View

```
<% form_tag projects_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

In Controller

```
def index
  @projects = Project.search(params[:search])
end
```

In Models

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```