# Using user input to query MySQL database and move to next page or display error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

When accessing the first page of our site, users are prompted to enter a "coupon code" to continue to the next page. Coupons can be used multiple times, but must exist in the "code" field of the coupon_codes table.

If the user enters a code that exists in the coupon_codes table, they should automatically be redirected to the next page. If the user enters a code that does not exist in the coupon_codes table, an error should be displayed with the option of trying again.

I'm sure I'm making this more difficult than it needs to be, as I've been working on this on and off for days. I've been able to get it to be what I feel is close, but not quite there. There have been multiple variations and trials, but this is where I'm currently at.

Model (coupon_code):

```
def self.code(code)
  if code
    self.exists?(['code = ?', "#{code}"])
    ##move on to /design
  else
    ##display error
  end
end
```

View (index):

```
<%= form_tag coupon_code, :method => 'get' do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :code, params[:code] %>
    <%= submit_tag("Check my coupon", :name => nil) %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def index
  @coupon_codes = CouponCode.code(params[:code])
end
```

The log shows the following (after entering the correct code) before re-rendering the page I'm already on:

```
CouponCode Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `coupon_codes` WHERE (code = 'correct') LIMIT 1
```

If I use the rails console, it seems like it should work (assuming I'm using it correctly), I'm just not sure how to go about getting it to move on or display an error.

```
2.1.1 :001 > code = 'correct'
  => "correct" 
2.1.1 :002 > CouponCode.exists?(['code = ?', "#{code}"])
  CouponCode Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `coupon_codes` WHERE (code = 'T001') LIMIT 1
D, [2017-08-17T11:08:32.730761 #6788] DEBUG -- :   CouponCode Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `coupon_codes` WHERE (code = 'correct') LIMIT 1
  => true 
2.1.1 :003 > code = 'wrong'
  => "wrong" 
2.1.1 :004 > CouponCode.exists?(['code = ?', "#{code}"])
  CouponCode Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `coupon_codes` WHERE (code = 'wjorea') LIMIT 1
D, [2017-08-17T11:09:10.611964 #6788] DEBUG -- :   CouponCode Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `coupon_codes` WHERE (code = 'wrong') LIMIT 1
  => false
```

Again, I'm sure it's something simple and I'm just over thinking it. Sorry if I gave way too much detail... I figured too much is better than not enough. Thank you in advance for any help or direction!

My current code is based off of parts of [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694416/rails-how-can-a-user-input-data-into-an-active-record-query), if that helps any.

Comment: Note that in ActiveRecord most of the time you can replace `['x=?', x]` with `{ x: x }` which is much more succinct.

Comment: Good to know! Thank you, @tadman!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the model is not and should not be concerned with controller or view issues. Redirecting to another page is explicitly a controller issue and must be handled directly in the controller.

What you want to do is reduce your model's code to an advisory position, it will *advise* the controller on how to handle the request. It will not take direct action.

For example:

```
class CouponCode
  def self.code_exists?(code)
    self.exists?(code: code)
  end
end
```

Then in the controller:

```
if (Coupon.code_exists?(params[:code]))
  redirect_to(coupon_exists_path(...))
end
```

Given how simple your check is, though, it's not clear if having such a method in the model is of any use since the alternative is simply:

```
if (Coupon.exists?(code: params[:code]))
  redirect_to(coupon_exists_path(...))
end
```

That's one character more code on the controller and three lines less on the model.

Comment: Ah ha! What you said makes complete sense. Thank you! I had tried calling the controller from the method so I could tell it to redirect to the next page, but then read that that's a no-go, which also made sense. Your suggested code also worked for moving on, I just need to get an error message to display (hopefully without the page reloading).

Comment: If you `return redirect_to` then that will preclude anything else from happening in your controller which means if you put code after the `if` block you can do whatever you need, up to and including setting `flash.now[:error]` or whatever. Remember, the default action is to render out the template with the name of the controller action, so just let it do that.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm just not sure how to go about getting it to move on or display an
>   error.

You need to put that code in the **controller**. Its the controller's job to handle such things. Also you **don't need** a model method here. To keep the things straight forward and simple, try the below

```
def index 
  if CouponCode.exists?(code: params[:code])
    #code for redirect to next page
  else
    flash.now[:notice] = "Your error message"
  end
end
```

Comment: I was SO close to this with one of my other tries, but I wasn't making the connection to it. (I had it in a different "check the coupon" method in the controller. Good news though... this worked great for instances when the correct code is entered, but the error message isn't displaying anywhere that I can see (including the log). Do I need to reference it in the view? Instead of it displaying, the page reloads with the incorrect coupon code displayed in the url.